# What is the best practice to update child table in one to many relation in spring boot

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot

what is the best practice for updating child table. is it good if I use delete insert ? or from the Front-End should send different data which contain data to update and data to insert. Thanks

Comment: Try cascading options

Comment: you can use the `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET ...` see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) if you have any doubt about the conflicts with the data you want to insert. What do you mean with "child" table ? If it is a table which is referenced by other tables with foreign keys, then you can automatically propagate the update/delete on the foreign keys from the referencing tables to the referenced table.